# GPS Coordinate Handling

Tags: shapefile, gps, mif

I have a text file with consecutive coordinates of gps data  for ongoing and incoming route(on Same road). i want to convert them in line format. how can i normalise those extra coordinate so that i get only single line for a single route.

Comment: Could you include which software you are using?

Comment: i am using ruby code to generate mif file, after that i will open it in manifold Systems, but multiple lines are coming for a single road as i have huge number of gps data in text file with some fields(Lat Long time Date) for a single route.